# How can I delegate function from one class to another?

Tags: vb.net

I have a few forms which contains some same functions for work `DataGridView` with (CellClick, EditParams etc). Depending some event, function (with the personal params) must be start. As so some of functions in various forms is a same, I decided write they in separate class and call they from there. BUT if I have no problem with the control's events, I have problem with associating personal function with the class.
For example in the form's class I have a function:

```
Private Sub StartByCellClick(ByVal Arg1 As Object, ByVal Arg2 As Boolean)
    If Arg2 Then Arg1 = "Test1" Else Arg1 = "Test2"
End Sub
```

And I have a class `Class1`. So how can I send function (ByRef) `StartByCellClick` from `FormClass` to `Class1`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that code makes sense, given that you're setting the value of a parameter passed by value. Regardless, you can create a delegate and pass that around to be invoked wherever you like.  Gneerally speaking, you should use an `Action` or `Func` delegate with appropriate generic type parameters, If your method has a `ByRef` parameter though, I would assume that you would have to declare your own delegate type.

Comment: Ok. If I remove theese papams  what I must write?  I googling a lot, but I don't understand how write it. 
What I must write in form class and what in Class1?

Comment: [How to: Invoke a Delegate Method (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/how-to-invoke-a-delegate-method)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I did It!